# Haskell List of tuples to list?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to convert a list of tuples `[(Int,Int)]` as a generic way which valid to any input size ? .. i saw in various questions thats its not possible generically

example :

```
type X = [(Int,Int)]


func :: X -> [Int]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is not very certain about how the tuples should be converted into a list. I assume that you want to have them flattend - for instance, `[(1,2),(3,4)]` should become `[1,2,3,4]`.

This translation is only possible, if the two elements of your tuple are of the same type.  In this case you can do something like this:

```
tupleToList :: [(a,a)] -> [a]
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
tupleToList _          = []
```

In the general case, such a translation is impossible. One thing I could imagine to make the impossible possible is to use `Either` to wrap up the two different types:

```
tupleToList :: [(a,b)] -> [Either a b]
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = Left a : Right b : tupleToList xs
```

Comment: or `(>>= \(a,b) -> [Left a,Right b])`

Answer (score 11):

The [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library handles this and similar cases consistently.

```
> import Control.Lens
> toListOf (traverse . both) [(1,2),(3,4)]
            ^          ^
            |          |> Traversal of the tuple (a, a)
            |> Traversal of a list [b]
[1,2,3,4]
```

To convert from a list of lists:

```
> toListOf (traverse . traverse) [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

addition edit:

### `traverse` works with [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable)

`traverse` will work with any datatype that has a `Traversable` instance, for example trees.

```
> import Data.Tree
> let t = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [], Node 4 []], Node 5 []]
> let prettyTree = drawTree . fmap show
> prettyTree t
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 3
|  |
|  `- 4
|
`- 5
> toListOf (traverse . traverse) [t, t]
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also use a fold and avoid explicit recursion:

```
tupleToList = foldr (\(f,s) a -> f : s : a) []
```

Or:

```
tupleToList = foldl (\a (f,s) -> a ++ [f,s]) []
```

(For elements of the same type)

Answer (score 2):

This can be also achieved by the [homogeneous tuples library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98) (disclaimer: which I'm the author of). It defines wrappers for tuples that make them instances of `Traversable` (and others such as `Applicative` and `Monad`). So a tuple can be converted to a list by `toList . Tuple2` (where [toList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v%3atoList) is from `Data.Foldable`) and

```
f :: [(a, a)] -> [a]
f = concatMap (toList . Tuple2)
```

You can also use it for other tuples, for example `concatMap (toList . Tuple5)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
f [] = []
f [(x, y) : xs] = x : y : f xs
```

Comment: [(x,y) : xs] is of type [[(a,a)]]