# Convert List of Tuples to List of Lists Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have `[("m","n"),("p","q"),("r","s")]`. How can I convert it to `[["m","n"],["p","q"],["r","s"]]`?

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell List of tuples to list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270214/haskell-list-of-tuples-to-list)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write a single function to convert a pair to a list:

```
pairToList :: (a, a) -> [a]
pairToList (x,y) = [x,y]
```

Then you only have to `map` `pairToList`:

```
tuplesToList :: [(a,a)] -> [[a]]
tuplesToList = map pairToList
```

Or in a single line:

```
map (\(x,y) -> [x,y])
```

Comment: Newbie question - what's the \ for?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thats just syntax for defining a lambda.

Answer (score 14):

Using [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) you can do this succinctly for arbitrary length homogenous tuples:

```
import Control.Lens

map (^..each) [("m","n"),("p","q"),("r","s")] -- [["m","n"],["p","q"],["r","s"]]
map (^..each) [(1, 2, 3)] -- [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Note though that the `lens` library is complex and rather beginner-unfriendly.

Answer (score 10):

List comprehension version:

```
[[x,y] | (x,y) <- [("m","n"),("p","q"),("r","s")]]
```