# Find connected components from lists of edges

Tags: haskell

I need to find the connected components of a graph given its edges.

The graph edges are represented as a list of tuples, and the result needs to be a list of lists of vertices representing the connected components,
eg `[(1,2), (2,3), (2,6), (5,6) (6,7), (8,9), (9,10)] -> [[1,2,3,5,6,7], [8,9,10]]`.
There could be any number of connected edges and unconnected graph components in the list. The tuples will always be in ascending order though, if that helps.

I have the signature `groupEdges :: [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]` but I just can't think of how to get from tuples to lists.

I thought of taking one tuple at a time and searching the rest for matching elements, but I don't know how to make this list of sublists.

This question is *similar* to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149524/algorithm-for-getting-largest-connected-component-from-list-of-touching-pairs) on the CS Stack Exchange, but I don't want to use Data.Graph. I would like to do this without other packages if possible.

-- edit - comments from chepner and ThibautM have given me the first step. I can convert from tuples to lists by calling the function with `groupEdges map (\(x,y) -> [x,y]) pairs`.

Now I need to take this list of lists and group the connected components eg. `[[1,2], [2,3], [2,6], [5,6], [6,7], [8,9], [9,10]] -> [[1,2,3,5,6,7], [8,9,10]]`

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449231/convert-list-of-tuples-to-list-of-lists-haskell)

Comment: @ThibautM That's good for the first step, then I don't have to work with tuples. Grouping the numbers is the next step. I'll keep working on that

Comment: @MichaelLitchard any particular reason? what should I do to make this a valid question?

Comment: I've edited the answer to focus more on the actual problem (finding connected components from the edges of a graph) and less on how edges and connected components are represented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned not using packages. The 4 functions I used are relatively easy to implement yourself if you really want. (And I encourage you to either do so or at least lookup their implementation)

Lists are used as set, which is a lot worse in performance than using a dedicated structure e.g. Data.Set. Using a disjoint-set (union-find, merge-find) data structure (referenced in your linked answer) would be even better, but probably not very good as a starting point for understanding

```hs
import Data.List (elem, intersect, union, partition)

pairs = [(1,2), (2,3), (2,6), (5,6), (6,7), (8,9), (9,10)]
pairs2 = map (\(x,y) -> [x,y]) pairs

-- add item to list, only if its no already present - using list as set
addItem item list | elem item list = list
                  | otherwise      = item : list

-- used to test whether subgraphs are connected i.e. contain common node
intersects a b = not $ null $ intersect a b

unionAll :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
unionAll (x1:x2:xs) = unionAll ((union x1 x2):xs)
unionAll [x] = x
unionAll [] = []

-- find edges that are connected to first edge/subgraph and merge them
groupFirst :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
groupFirst (x:xs) = (unionAll (x:connected)) : disconnected
    where
-- separate 'xs' edges/subgraphs into those that are connected to 'x' and the rest
      (connected, disconnected) = partition (intersects x) xs
groupFirst [] = []

-- if no more edges/subgraphs can be connected with first edge, continue with remaining (disconnected) edge/subgraph ([5,6] in second iteration)
groupAll :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
groupAll (x:xs) = y:(groupAll ys)
    where
      (y:ys) = groupFirst (x:xs)
groupAll [] = []

-- after first 'groupAll pairs2' - [[1,2,3,6],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]

-- repeat this process until no more components can be connected together
groupAllRepeat x = if x /= groupAll x then groupAllRepeat (groupAll x) else x

main = print (groupAllRepeat pairs2)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - this algorithm takes the list and finds as many sublists as it can that intersect and joins them together. When it can find no more it repeats the process on the sublists after those, until it reaches the end of the list. Then it checks if the list would be the same if the process repeated, and repeats if it would be ?

Comment: 1. yes, that intersects with first not yet merged sublist (first element of passed list in `groupFirst`). 2. yes. 3. repeats the process if something was changed/merged in last iteration. This is done because in previous iteration only original subgraph is checked for intersection, not the intermediate merged. E.g `[1,2,3,6],[5,6,7]` were not merged together in first iteration, beacuse intersection with `[1,2]` was checked, not `[1,2,3,6]`, so with e.g. [5,6] didn't have any common node. You could try doing that instead, but "repeat until nothing changes" would have to be moved there instead.

Comment: I see, I get it. I was wondering how it would ever know when to stop, but that makes sense. Thank you!