# list of tuples into list with list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Is there any function or method in Haskell which helps me to take a list of tuples, for example `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]` and
returns `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and works with list comprehension?

I'm specifically searching for a function which takes a parameter `xs` and
has in body (of the function) a list comprehension.

Comment: You may look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270214/haskell-list-of-tuples-to-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell List of tuples to list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270214/haskell-list-of-tuples-to-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the list of tuples is named `ts`, we can perform iteration twice:

```
[ t | (a, b) <- ts, t <- [a, b] ]
```

So here we first iterate over the tuples `(a, b)` in `ts`, next we construct a new list `[a, b]`, and we iterate over that list as well, and we yield `t` for every `t` in `[a, b]`.

Or with a point-free list monad:

```
(>>= uncurry ((. pure) . (:)))
```

Comment: Incidentally, the point-free version would be clearer as `(uncurry (:) . second (:[]) =<<)`: “cons the first element onto the second element wrapped in a list for each pair”. (`second` is from `Control.Arrow` and in this case can be replaced with `fmap`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, process any list, even a list of tuples in a list comprehension. It is the form that is different. You see in the two great answers before this, the form is (a,b) or (x,y). These both mean the same. They mean two elements in a tuple. The problem with processing the tuple form is that the output are individual, two item lists. This is why `concat` is so valuable.

I do like list comprehensions so very much and the classic form for flattening a list of any kind with a list comprehension is given above.

I am relatively new to Haskell and had trouble understanding how `fold`s could produce a list and not a single value like `sum` or `product`.

Questions like this are invaluable because they help me understand.

The `foldr` version of this results in a list. The list you want. Why is it a list and not a single value? It is because `foldr` produces a series of successively larger and larger lists with the last largest being the answer.

Here is a `foldr` version of the function to flatten a tuple list.

```
foldr (\(a,b) l-> a:b:l) []    [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

[1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 1):

```
concatMap (\(x, y) -> [x, y]) [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

will give

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

If you don't want to use `concatMap` you can do

```
concat . map (\(x, y) -> [x, y])
```

Comment: `concatMap` is defined in `Data.Foldable` and so must be `imported`.
`concat.map` works the same without importing.

Comment: @fpmora Hoogle says it is also in the base prelude

Comment: My bad. I thought not. It's great to know, Thank you.