# explain this haskell funtion "list of tuples to list"

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner and basically I need an explanation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270263/9821997)

He answer with this code:

```
tupleToList :: [(a,a)] -> [a]
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
tupleToList _          = []
```

But I don't underdand why he don't use:

```
tupleToList [] = []
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
```

Like I usually see in the first exercises of the guides.
I know that '_' is whatever, but, isn't better to use '[]' that mean, when the list is empty?

Comment: I'm a Haskell beginner as well... but I believe they're equivalent. Yours looks nicer to me. (Though I would prefer putting the `[]` case on the second line.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Like I usually see in the first exercises of the guides. I know that `_` is whatever, but, isn't better to use `[]` that mean, when the list is empty?

Semantically the two are the same since a 2-tuple has only one constructor `(a,b)`, and a list has two constructors `[]` and `(h:t)`.

Since the only pattern left that is not matched by the first clause is the empty list, the *wildcard* `_` is equivalent to `[]`.

Since `[]` and `((a,b):xs)` are *disjunctive* patterns (i.e. there are no values that can match both patterns), the order of the two patterns is of no importance, when `[]` is used explicitly. We can write it in any order we like, then.

Some Haskell programmers prefer to use *explicit* patterns (so with `[]` instead of `_`), since that means that we know which values we actually handle with that clause. If later the Haskell community would decide to introduce an additional list constructor (yes, for lists that is very unlikely, but for other `data` types this might be more reasonable), the Haskell compiler can (with `-Wincomplete-patterns`) give warnings that some patterns are not covered. A wildcard of course covers *all* patterns, but perhaps the expression at the right is not the one we intended for the additional constructor.

Therefore I would advice to use a wildcard *only* in case you want to match *multiple* patterns by the same clause. In case it is clear what the other pattern is, it is better to be explicit. Like the *Zen of Python* says (yes, it is Python, but most concepts are to some extent universal): "*explicit is better than implicit*".

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference: their semantics is exactly the same.

```
tupleToList [] = []
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
```

is equivalent to

```
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
tupleToList [] = []
```

which is equivalent to

```
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs
tupleToList _ = []
```

Usually, the wildcard `_` is used when we need to pattern match multiple cases. E.g.

```
myAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
myAnd True  y = y
myAnd False _ = False
```

Above, we could enumerate the `False False` and `False True` cases individually, and use three equations, but using a wildcard is more convenient (and makes our function slightly lazier, e.g. `myAnd False undefined` evaluates to `False`).

Concluding, it's mostly a matter of style. Usually, when the wildcard `_` can only stand for one case, it *is* better to spell it out, to be explicit about it. In this way, the code is often more readable. E.g.

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
not False = True
not _     = False
```

is equivalent but worse than

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
not False = True
not True  = False
```

The same holds for `case` expression, of course.

```
case x of
  Just y  -> 1 + y
  Nothing -> 0
```

is arguably more readable than

```
case x of
  Just y -> 1 + y
  _      -> 0
```